# Error with JavaScript promise and then condition

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm learning JavaScript promises and `then`, and am confused with this error using Node.js.

I would like `dostart()` to wait until nonblocking sleep is finished, and then return "Resolved" to the main function when it is done.

I get this error:

> dostart().then(value => {
> ---------^
> **TypeError**: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

Help appreciated :)

```js
function nonBlockingSleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function dostart() {
  console.log("Hello2");

  nonBlockingSleep(2000).then(() => {
    console.log("Done");
    return Promise.resolve("Resolved");
  });
}

dostart().then(value => {
  // main function - I'd like console.log to show "Resolved" when dostart() is finished
  console.log(value);
})
```

Comment: `doStart()` doesn't return anything explicitly, nor is it marked `async`. Thus it automatically produces `undefined`.

Comment: `return nonBlockingSleep(2000).then(....)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dostart` isn't `async` and doesn't *return* the promise from `then`, so you can't try to consume that promise where you call it.

You have at least a couple of options.

The simple one in this particular case is to return the promise from `then`:

```js
function nonBlockingSleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function dostart() {
    console.log("Hello2");

    // *** Return the promise
    return nonBlockingSleep(2000).then(() => {
        console.log("Done");
        // *** There's no need for `Promise.resolve` here, `then`
        // _always_ returns a promise, and will use the return value
        // here to fulfill it. (If you return a promise instead, it will
        // resolve its promise to the promise you return instead of
        // fulfilling its promise.)
        return "Fulfilled";
    });
}

dostart().then((value) => {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Your other option is to use `async`/`await`:

```js
function nonBlockingSleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// *** Make `dostart` an `async` function
async function dostart() {
    console.log("Hello2");

    // *** `await` the promise from `nonBlockingSleep`
    await nonBlockingSleep(2000);
    console.log("Done");
    // *** Return the fulfillment value for this function's promise
    return "Fulfilled";
}

dostart().then((value) => {
    console.log(value);
});
```

---

Side note: I changed `"Resolved"` to `"Fulfilled"` because we're *fulfilling* the promise in that particular case. It's common, but incorrect, to use "resolve" for "fulfill." It's true that fulfilling a promise resolves it, but the converse isn't true — resolving a promise doesn't always fulfill it. It might leave it pending, or even eventually reject it, if you resolve it *to* another promise. I've written up promise terminology in [this blog post](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/02/08/lets-talk-about-how-to-talk-about-promises/).

Comment: @Sylv99  - My pleasure! For what it's worth, I explain promises thoroughly in Chapter 8 of [*JavaScript: The New Toys*](https://thenewtoys.dev) and move on to `async`/`await` in Chapter 9. :-)

Answer (score -2):

since `dostart` returns nothing you can fix it like this:

```js
function dostart() {
    console.log("Hello2");

    return nonBlockingSleep(2000).then(() => { console.log("Done"); return Promise.resolve("Resolved"); });
}
```

or use keyword `async`

```js
async function dostart() {
    console.log("Hello2");

    return await nonBlockingSleep(2000).then(() => { console.log("Done"); return Promise.resolve("Resolved"); });
}
```

Comment: The first code is correct. The second doesn't work as intended. (Not my downvote)

Comment: The second example still doesn't do what the OP asked after your edit. It will wait, but it won't fulfill its promise with `"Resolved"` (it will fulfill it with `undefined`). Also, mixing `async`/`await` with explicit calls to `then` or `catch` is an anti-pattern 99% of the time.